# Pasting with colours and formatting Google Document

Tags: google-docs, copy-paste

I've copied some sample code from Visual Studio 2013 (in Microsoft Windows 8).
I'm doing ctrl + v to paste into an online Google Document.

The paste loses all the formatting and text.
Is there anyway to get around this?

We don't want to paste a screenshot, as we want editable text which retains color + formatting.

Comment: Import a screenshot....

Comment: We want editable text. I'll amend the question

Answer (score 2):

Without a sample from Visual Studio 2013 (in Microsoft Windows 8) to hand, I can't be sure but believe enhancements to Docs since OP was posted have changed the circumstances upon which the question was based. Certainly now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> does not lose "all the formatting and text", necessarily.

For example the clip on the left is from Word and on the right from Docs after the text in Word was pasted there:

[image: Word] [image: Docs]

There were changes around the time the web clipboard was ['retired'](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/05/web-clipboard-to-be-removed-from-google.html) in September 2017.

Answer (score -3):

I use this way: from Visual Studio I copy to MS Word, from there I copy to Google Doc so the fonts are retained.